# Encode and Decode multilingual string c#

Tags: c#, .net, encode, multilingual

I want to encode and then decode a string that contains multilingual characters, in which the language, length and character positioning (like, chinese character on indexes 8-10) are unknown.

Is it even possible to have a "universal" encoder? Or some algorithm that knows how to decode this?

Searching the web came up with only solutions that involved knowing where the special characters are, and of what language, and I cant even know the language itself.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Example: a string that consists of several languages, such as:

> "Hello {CHINESE} my {LATIN} is rusted"

which consists of english, chinese, and latin.

But when I do

```
var test = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(someStr);
```

and then

```
ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(test)
```

the "special characters" (IE, not english characters) are converted to question marks

Comment: What do you mean by "encode"? What context makes some characters "special"? No character is any more special than any other other than in a given context (e.g. `漢` is special in URLs but not in HTML).

Comment: Can you provide some examples? Right now it is unclear what is your concrete problem and what is your goal.

Comment: UTF16 (and UTF8) are perfectly good encodings that support all the characters that you'll use :-)

Comment: Ok... So don't use `ASCIIEncoding`? It is a relic of a bygone era... Use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`. and `Encoding.UTF8.GetString`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use ASCII encoding since it isn't supposed to handle multiple language characters in the same string.

Use Unicode instead:

```
var test = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(someStr);
var test1 = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(test);
```

Comment: Which one is better? UnicodeEncoding or Encoding.UTF8.GetString ?

Comment: @TomerSomething if your text mostly contains latin characters - then UTF8 can be better for you. `UnicodeEncoding.Unicode` is in fact UTF16.